# Does multiplication by the inverse of a Cholesky matrix preserve order?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, order-theory

Let $n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ and let $C \in \mathbb{R}_{n, n}$ be a real, symmetric and positive definite $n \times n$ matrix. Define $B \in \mathbb{R}_{n, n}$ to be the real, lower triangular matrix with positive diagonal entries, such that $C = BB^T$ is $C$'s Cholesky's decomposition.

1. Is it true that, for every pair of real column vectors $x, y \in \mathbb{R}_{n, 1}$ of length $n$, we have
   $$
   x \leq y \implies B^{-1}x \leq B^{-1}y
   $$
   where the inequalities are to be interpreted component-wise?
2. Is it true that
   $$
   \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} B^{-1}y = \infty
   $$
   where $y \in \mathbb{R}_{n, 1}$ "lives" in the set of real column vectors of length $n$, and convergence to infinity is to be interpreted component-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Is not true. This is only true if all entries of $B^{-1}$ are non-negative. Assume the $(i,j)$-th entry of $B^{-1}$ is negative. Then choosing $x = e_j$, $y=2e_j$ yields $B^{-1}x\not\le B^{-1}y$.

2) Is not true. Not all components of $B^{-1}y$ will converge to infinity: Take $B^{-1}=\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 0&1}$. Then 
$$
B^{-1} \pmatrix{ k \\ k } = \pmatrix{ 0 \\ k}.
$$

The claim is true if convergence to infinity is meant as $\|y\|\to\infty$.